# Replace values in a numerical range

Tags: r

Hi guys a very simple question. 
How can I replace `values  < 1.5` and  the `values  > -1.5`  with `0` in a `data.frame`? 
Should be "pipe" the best solution?

Thanks a lot!

E.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s as simple as this:

```
data[data > -1.5 & data < 1.5] <- 0
```

Answer (score 6):

`replace` offers another option.

```
replace(DF, DF > -1.5 & DF < 1.5, 0)
```

This function allows for simpler syntax in the cases where you have to replace values across a number of `data.frame`s stored in a list.

```
# list of data.frames
dframes <- replicate(3, data.frame(a=seq(-2, 2, by=1), b=seq(2, -2, by=-1)), simplify=FALSE)
# perform the replacement across all DFs in the list.
lapply(dframes, function(DF) replace(DF, DF > -1.5 & DF < 1.5, 0))
```

Otherwise, you'd have to write something like

```
lapply(dframes, function(DF) {DF[DF > -1.5 & DF < 1.5] <- 0;DF})
```

Answer (score 3):

Konrad's solution is more generalizable but in this specific case it might make sense to just use a comparison involving the absolute value.

```
> dat <- data.frame(x = seq(-2, 2), y = rnorm(5))
> dat
   x           y
1 -2 -1.48698044
2 -1 -0.05863244
3  0  1.75314296
4  1 -0.72946147
5  2 -0.74845237
> dat$x[abs(dat$x) < 1.5] <- 0
> dat
   x           y
1 -2 -1.48698044
2  0 -0.05863244
3  0  1.75314296
4  0 -0.72946147
5  2 -0.74845237
```